# How does hash_file work in PHP for password protected files?

Tags: php, hash

I was wondering how hash_file works? The PHP manual states: 
hash_file — Generate a hash value using the contents of a given file.

So I thought what if I password protect a zip file. Apparently it can still get the contents. So this made me wonder how is the hash value computed for files? Maybe the file header? If anyone knows I would love to know.

Comment: There is absolutely no relation between a password protects a ZIP file and a hash of a file computed with `hash_file()`. None whatsoever. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Comment: thank you for your brief comment. If you have an answer to the question I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that `hash_file` requires the unencoded contents of a given file. It does not. In the context of `hash_file`, contents means the bits of a file as they are written to the disk. If a file happens to be encoded or encrypted then it will happily take the scrambled contents and produce a hash for that.

Comment: Thanks FuzzyTree! that was what I was looking for. In got this impression, because i saw somewhere that hash("md5", file_get_contents("filename.moo"));  was the same. So I thought it has to be opened then or something. but that was a brainfart :)